# Magento 2: How to load another customer data on checkout instead of current logged in customer via custom module?

Tags: php, session, magento2, checkout

I want to show a customers list as dropdown on checkout page and when I change the customer from that dropdown list, All details like shipping addresses, customer detail should be change according to that selected customer. But the current loggedin customer should not logout and order should be place for selected customer from that dropdown list.

Best solutions are warmly welcome please!
Also posted on Magento Stack:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265315/magento-2-how-to-load-another-customer-data-on-checkout-instead-of-current-logg

Comment: Have you tried event observers?

Comment: Yes I have tried the checkout before event observer but Its not working...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, It'll help you.

Define your event like the following

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
    <event name='checkout_submit_before'>
        <observer
                name='Arhamsoft_Order_Order_BeforeCheckout'
                instance='Arhamsoft\Order\Observer\BeforeCheckout'
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now Create Observer for that

```
<?php 

namespace MODULE\Order\Observer; 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager;
 /*** For Override Success Page **/
class BeforeCheckout implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface { 

     protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_orderFactory;    
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(        
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager $objectManager
    ) {
    }

    /*** For Save SA ID  And Other Attributes Values **/
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) { 

    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to be working let me modify it according to my requirements.

Comment: Thanks  for your efforts now I can use any kind of preprocessors in magento . Thanks again